# Indeterminate checkbox in react without ref

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I am trying to implement a triple-state checkbox to react without using ref method.
I found a lot of solutions with ref.
For example:

```
const { value, checked, indeterminate } = this.props

return render(
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={value}
        checked={checked}
        ref={el => el && (el.indeterminate = indeterminate)}
    />
)
```

**I need a component implementation with ref method**

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly. Why can't you just pass `indeterminate={indeterminate}` to the `input` element?

Comment: No you can't juste put <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={value}
        checked={checked}
        indeterminate={indeterminate}
    />